# Efficient Management of Conditional Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Is there some more intelligent way of managing rules of conditional formatting than the obvious conditional formatting manager? I have spreadsheets with numerous rules that are built around very complex formulas and the manager is just not up to the task in these points:

1. It is quite difficult to put in long, complex formulas because the rule formula bar is like 7 cm long while the formula can go several times its length
2. If I want essentially the same rule with small modifications, there is no way of duplicating an existing rule, I need to create a new one and copy the formulas manually.
3. There is no possibility to annotate. When I have 10 rules with complex formulas (sometimes super complex, just to make the number of rules smaller), it is very difficult to understand what the purpose of each one is after a while (especially if the formula is 2 feet long and I can see it only in the 7 cm bar...). When I put a regular formula in a cell, I can put a comment to annotate. When I write a piece of code, I can indent it and put in comments. But with rules of formatting? Nada.

Is there some way around these limitations?

Answer (score 1):

The main interface for managing conditional formattings in Excel is the form you've mentioned. There is no better alternative for that.

However you may find some alternatives:

- You can build and test your formula in a cell, then just copy it to the field in conditional formatting.
  This way you don't need to remember everything by heart and can quickly check whether it works or not.
- More sophisticated way could be to have a support sheet where you keep your conditional format information (target range, formula, format...) and have a macro which loads this information in conditional formatting.
  This could solve majority of your problems (you can also add comments), however requires efforts to set it up, also your workbook won't be macro free.

  - You can also look for add-ins already having this possibility, maybe somebody had already the same issue and published his solution.

Comment: Hmmm... I like the help sheet solution. Albeit my current predicament excludes any possibility of macro enabled workbook, I can imagine having a developer version of the workbook, importing the rules by a macro and exporting to a macro-free workbook...

Answer (score 1):

I use tables for this.

If you highlight your rectangle of data and insert a table, then you can start using formulas that are the same throughout the entire column, [referring to other columns by their column title rather than "B4"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-F5ED2452-2337-4F71-BED3-C8AE6D2B276E). I make hidden columns by filling the column's title cell with red to give me a reminder that I need to right-click and hide that column when I'm done, and place comments about that column however it makes sense. Because it's in a table, every time I add a row, formulas are automatically applied to the new row without making me copy/paste.

Once I do this, managing my conditional formatting is much easier because

- the conditional formulas be simple, referring to my hidden columns, rather than contain the complicated formulas within the conditional formatting.
- I can trouble-shoot conditional formulas much more easily because I can see the values for each row.
- The complicated formulas are easier to understand because formulas within a table can (and should) refer to other columns within the table by their column title rather than "B4", which makes them much more readable.
- Computation of the same conditional formatting formula to multiple columns is more efficient because they can re-use the same calculations cached within those hidden columns rather than recalculate them.
- Even if you don't make comments in your hidden columns, you at least can give a column title that will be very helpful to yourself.

This won't alleviate all of your pain, but it will go a long way!

Comment: That sounds like a good approach, unfortunately not applicable universally, e.g. in my most recent case I am developing an Excel form, which needs to adhere to certain business requirements about layout and I can imagine it working with tables. Also not sure about the hidden columns - does that not make the formatting even more obscure since the formulas are referring to things that you cannot even see without a conscious effort?

Comment: Not really. Unfortunately the conditional formulas cannot refer to structured names, they must use the Column-Row format, and as such they refer to columns that are very obviously hidden once you look for them. Furthermore, if you don't use those columns and put the logic in the conditional format formulas then your formulas are just as complex, if not more so, and you couldn't see the values to help figure out what's going on even if you did unhide everything. It's much easier to understand what a formula is doing when you can see the values that formula produces.